# Unable to find specific subclass of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

I'm working on developing an app with Core Data. When I created an instance using:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext)
let user = User(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext)
```

I got a warning in log:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'User' for entity 'User'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

How could I fix it?

And another question, how can I define an instance method in NSManagedObject subclass?

Edit:

I have specified class of the entity as in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you prefixed the entities class name with the module name, as documented in [Implementing Core Data Managed Object Subclasses](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html) ?

Comment: @MartinR: See my question's update.

Comment: The class should be " YourAppName.User", see the documentation (link in my previous comment).

Comment: The best thing is to delete those classes and re create it. This worked for me

Answer (score 221, accepted):

**Update for Xcode 7 (final):** 
Prepending the module name to the class (as in Xcode 6 and early beta releases of Xcode 7) is no longer necessary.
The Apple documentation  [Implementing Core Data Managed Object Subclasses](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-ID105) has been
updated accordingly.

The Data Model inspector
has now two fields "Class" and "Module" for an entity:

[image]

When you create a Swift managed object subclass for the entity, the
"Module" field is set to "Current Product Module", and with this setting
creating instances works both in the main application and in unit tests.
The managed object subclass must *not* be marked with `@objc(classname)` (this was observed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31288029/1187415).

*Alternatively,* you can empty the "Module" field (it will show "None") and mark the
managed object subclasses with `@objc(classname)` (this was observed 
in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31287260/1187415).

---

*Remark:* This answer was originally written for Xcode 6.
There were some changes in the various Xcode 7 beta releases with
respect to this problem. Since it is an accepted answer with many
upvotes and links to it, I have tried to summarize the situation
for the current Xcode 7 final version.

I did both my own "research" and read all the answers to both this question and the similar question
[CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613971/coredata-warning-unable-to-load-class-named). So attribution goes to all of them, even if I don't
list them specifically!

---

Previous  answer for **Xcode 6**:

As documented in [Implementing Core Data Managed Object Subclasses](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-XID_68), you have to
prefix the entities class name in the Class field in the model entity inspector with the name of your module, for example "MyFirstSwiftApp.User".

Comment: This one is working for me. Question: What if the core data is included in a framework, how to prefix the ManagedObject subclass name since there is no actual app yet?

Comment: @Allan: You could try the `@objc(ClassName)` method suggested in Christer's answer.

Comment: It works, but once I've set the class name to "APPNAME.User" in the entity inspector, I am unable to regenerate model classes: Xcode seems to be confused by the prefix, and it generates a file/class with the name APPNAME. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you show how generated swift file looks like if its parent entity is NSManagedObjet and if is other custom Entity? I got some strange file content and compile time errors.

Comment: What if you get this error in Objective-C when using core data in a static library?

Comment: @GeorgeTaskos: That looks like a different problem and seems already to be solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465485/coredata-warning-unable-to-load-class-named-weereadings-for-entity-readings.

Comment: @Martin R yes, posted the comment before I add my own question to stackoverflow.

Comment: I have hyphens in my project name, I replaced them with underscores in the class name, it works.

Comment: How can that work if you have two targets? your app and test?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz: For that case the solutions from Christer's or Ludovic's answer might be better suited for you.

Comment: It worked with the module prefix, I just would like to comment that the link is broken

Comment: @MartinR, the automatically generated `@objc(ClassName)` now needs to be removed.

Comment: @Suragch: I have now finally update the answer, I do hope that everything is correct now.

Comment: this worked for me: "Alternatively, you can empty the "Module" field (it will show "None") and mark the managed object subclasses with @objc(classname) (this was observed in ..."

Answer (score 62):

Just as a side-note. i had the same issue. And all i had to do was add `@objc(ClassName)` in my class file.

Example:

```
@objc(Person)
class Person { }
```

And that solved my issue.

Comment: You defined typealias (<%ProjectName%>.Person -> Person) in Objective-C in that way, so it works.

Comment: Seems like Apple forgot to fully convert it to the swift .. dont know why but this fixed it for me pretty gently

Comment: This is particularly useful if you have a project with multiple targets, where each target shares the CoreData model. In these cases, it is not possible to prefix the class name with that of the target identifier as that renders the CD model useful to only one of the targets.

Comment: @djbp And "why not?" I'd like to know. I like the concept of namespacing, but this made me want to throw my MacBook out the window (I have an app with an extension, and hit this problem when running the extension). There has to be a "right" way to do this with namespaces, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Yup this worked for me when working with shared data models in a workspace

Comment: This is the way to do it until they fix the subclass file naming bug in XCode

Comment: @S'pht'Kr And here we are, four months later with no solution. Unless anyone has a pleasing update?

Comment: This answer is no longer true.

Answer (score 31):

The accepted answer to this question helped me resolve the same issue but I had a caveat that I thought would be helpful to others. If your project (module) name has a space in it you must replace the space with an underscore. For example:

Entity:  MyEntity
Class:   My_App_Name.MyClass

Comment: When we set the class name with AppName.ClassName, Xcode 9 its remove the dot and create a class without a dot. So this is no longer in Xcode 9.*.

Answer (score 17):

Remember to remove your **module**:

[image]

Comment: This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 9):

Depending if you are running as App vs Tests the issue can be that the app is looking for `<appName>.<entityName>` and when it's running as test it's looking as `<appName>Tests.<entityName>`. The solution I use at this time (Xcode 6.1) is to NOT fill the `Class` field in the CoreData UI, and to do it in code instead.

This code will detect if you are running as App vs Tests and use the right module name and update the `managedObjectClassName`.

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional...
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Streak", withExtension: "momd")!
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!

    // Check if we are running as test or not
    let environment = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment as [String : AnyObject]
    let isTest = (environment["XCInjectBundle"] as? String)?.pathExtension == "xctest"

    // Create the module name
    let moduleName = (isTest) ? "StreakTests" : "Streak"

    // Create a new managed object model with updated entity class names
    var newEntities = [] as [NSEntityDescription]
    for (_, entity) in enumerate(managedObjectModel.entities) {
        let newEntity = entity.copy() as NSEntityDescription
        newEntity.managedObjectClassName = "\(moduleName).\(entity.name)"
        newEntities.append(newEntity)
    }
    let newManagedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel()
    newManagedObjectModel.entities = newEntities

    return newManagedObjectModel
}()
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm getting "fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type" when casting the NSManagedObject to its actual class. Actually not when casting itself, but when trying to go into a for loop.

Comment: That example does not work if you have any sort of inheritance in your model. For every new entity you also need to iterate over subentites and update them with the new entities you created.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a hyphen in your project name like "My-App" then use an underscore instead of the hyphen like "My_App.MyManagedObject".
In general, look at the name of the xcdatamodeld file and use the same prefix as in that name.
I.e. "My_App_1.xcdatamodeld" requires the prefix "My_App_1"

Comment: wow. Thank you thank you thank you. I'd be interested in knowing where in the Apple docs that little nugget is :)

Answer (score 5):

This may help those experiencing the same problem. I was, with Swift 2 and Xcode 7 beta 2.

[The solution](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5704) in my case was to comment out `@objc(EntityName)` in `EntityName.swift`.

Answer (score 3):

The above answers were helpful.  This quick sanity check may save you some time.  Go into Project > Build Phases > Compile Sources and remove your xcdatamodeld and your model files with the "-" button, and then add them right back with the "+" button.  Rebuild -- that may take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same warning, though my app appeared to run fine. 
The problem was that when running Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass on the last screen I used the default Group location, with no Targets displayed or checked, which saved the subclass in the top MyApp directory where MyApp.xcodeproj was located.
The warning went away when I instead changed the Group to be in the MyApp subfolder and checked the MyApp target.

Answer (score 2):

By the way be careful what you add as a prefix: My App is called "ABC-def" and Xcode has converted the "-" into a "_".

To be safe look into the finder, find your project files and see what it says for your data model (for example "ABC_def.xcdatamodeld") and use what is written there EXACTLY!!!

Answer (score 1):

The above answers helped me to solve different issue connected with Objective-C (maybe it will help someone):

If you refactored entity names, don't forget to change "Class" in "Utilities Panel" as well.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers helped me but this may help somebody. If like me you did them and are still having a problem, remember to simply 'clean your project'. For XCode8, Product > Clean. Then run again.

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode 7 Entity and Class names can be the same but Codegen should be Class Definition. In that case there will be no warning etc.

[image]