# CoreData - Equivalent of Using Categories w/ Example - Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

I'm wondering how to essentially create the equivalent of a Category for my CoreData NSManagedObject Client below:

I understand that Extensions are now the replacement of Categories in Swift - however am unsure of their implementation. Here is what I have deducted below:

```
class Client: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var projects: NSSet

}

extension Client {

    func addClientWithName(name:NSString, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Client {
        var client:Client = Client();

        // Check for name in the database already exists
        let request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Client")
        let sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptorsAry:NSArray = [sortDescriptor]
        request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptorsAry
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name)

        var error:NSError?
        let matches:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

        if matches.count == 0 {

            //Add new Client
            var newClient:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Client", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSEntityDescription
            newClient.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

            context.save(nil);

        } else {
            client = matches.lastObject as Client
        }

        return client
    }
}
```

With this implementation however, this is the error i get so far:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class "Ttc9AppName6Client"
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

**Edit:**
This is how i call the method from my other class:

```
@IBAction func saveBtnTapped(UIButton) {
    println("save btn tapped")
    var client:Client = Client().addClientWithName("Woofy Face", context: self.managedObjectContext)
}
```

Comment: Did you prefix the entities class name with the module name in the Core Data model inspector? Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/25076929/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR - i've double checked - Its definitely prefixed "AppName.Client"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is unrelated to categories/extensions.

```
 var client:Client = Client();
```

does *not* call the designated initializer of `NSManagedObject`, and this object
is returned if the fetch request found no matching object.

What you probably want is to return the newly created object in that case.

Note also that

```
insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:
```

returns a managed object, not an entity description.

In addition,

```
var client:Client = Client().addClientWithName(...)
```

also creates a Client object without using the designated initializer.
You should define the method as a *class method* instead.

So your code should look like this:

```
 class func addClientWithName(name:NSString, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Client {
    var client:Client

    let request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Client")
    let sortDescriptor:NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptorsAry:NSArray = [sortDescriptor]
    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptorsAry
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name)

    var error:NSError?
    let matches:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

    if matches.count == 0 {
        //Add new Client
        client = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Client", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Client
        client.name = name
        context.save(nil)
    } else {
        client = matches.lastObject as Client
    }
    return client
}
```

and it would be called as

```
let client:Client = Client.addClientWithName("Woofy Face", context: self.managedObjectContext)
```

Comment: Thanks: I see where you are coming from and have implemented your solution,- i still get however get: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class '_TtC9AppName6Client'

Comment: Note that your function should be a *class function* : `class func addClientWithName ...` and should be called as `let cl1 = Client.addClientWithName(...)`. - I now tested that code and it seemed to work.

Comment: I've just thrown into the IBAction and it works fine there, just not in the extension it seems

Comment: this is a great solution, but i cant implement it because im moving the objects through a protocol. embedding a class function doesnt remove the error. any ideas?

Comment: @Japes: Sorry, but I don't get what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks, but I found a solution. No worries.