# iOS8 CoreData "use of unimplemented initializer"

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I get the following error trying to run my application

fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(entity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)' for class 'rcresttest.CatalogItem'

I can bypass this error by changing the Entity's class in the data model to something else, but then I will get a swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional: when trying to downcast.

Is this a bug in beta6 or am I doing something wrong?

CatalogItem.swift

```
import CoreData

@objc(CatalogItem)

class CatalogItem : NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id : String
    @NSManaged var slug : String
    @NSManaged var catalogItemId : String

    init(entity: NSEntityDescription!, context: NSManagedObjectContext!, catalogResultsDict : NSDictionary) {
       super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
       id = catalogResultsDict["Id"] as String
       slug = catalogResultsDict["Slug"] as String
       catalogItemId = catalogResultsDict["CatalogItemId"] as String
    }
}
```

and the data model

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="" type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="6220.8" systemVersion="13E28" minimumToolsVersion="Xcode 4.3" macOSVersion="Automatic" iOSVersion="Automatic">
    <entity name="CatalogItem" representedClassName="CatalogItem" syncable="YES">
        <attribute name="catalogItemId" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
        <attribute name="id" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
        <attribute name="slug" optional="YES" attributeType="String" syncable="YES"/>
    </entity>
    <elements>
        <element name="CatalogItem" positionX="-45" positionY="0" width="128" height="90"/>
    </elements>
</model>
```

Edit:

After changing the name of the datamodel class to have the module prefix The error message appears after trying to cast.

2014-08-20 10:49:15.335 rcresttest[63516:4194127] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'rcresttest.CatalogItem' for entity 'CatalogItem'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

Comment: Objc isn't the right thing to use, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154117/in-swift-using-core-data-how-come-i-can-cast-to-nsmanagedobject-but-not-to-my

Comment: Have you prefixed the class in the model editor with the module name?

Comment: Yeah. Adding the prefix bypasses the error but causes the "swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional"

Comment: CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'rest_test.CatalogItem' for entity 'CatalogItem'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is with init method. Create method instead where you inserting entity.

Comment: @Shmidt Yeah looks like you are right. It doesn't like me overloading the init function, looks like it can't cast with it.

Comment: @puttputt read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107032/coredata-equivalent-of-using-categories-w-example-swift?rq=1

Answer (score 18):

This is a problem with the designated initializer. Just add `convenience` in front of your `init` and call `init(entity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)` on `self` instead `super`.