# Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios8

I have a problem with core data in IOS 8. Whenever I want to use the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` method, I get the

> Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

Error message. I use objective-c, and I did not had this problem using IOS 7. Also could there be any problem because in my workspace there are two projects, one containing the core data relating code, and the other the UI.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That error means that you've configured a custom class name for the entity type in the model editor, but that the class does not exist at run time. Core Data falls back on creating a generic `NSManagedObject` using the entity type.

Assuming that the class file actually exists somewhere, the problem is that you're not including that file in the app target in Xcode. Since Xcode supports multiple targets, projects, etc, it doesn't automatically include every source file in every build. Add the Core Data subclass file(s) to the app target and this error should go away.

Comment: It worked, I copied both the .h and .m files to the compile sources, and now there is no warning.

Comment: For me it was because I had created an `NSManagedObject` subclass, but auto generator didn't wrap the class name in `@objc` (even though my project is in Swift). Eg, for above the class declaration for a `Temperature`, add `@objc(Temperature)`

Comment: It can't be for XCtest cases.

Comment: It will leads to another error upfront. We should have a way to avoid adding these things on the test target.

Comment: File an issue with Apple and hope for the best. They don't read this site, so tell them directly.

Answer (score 32):

### This is an updated version from the answer provided from @High6

As of Xcode 7 there is a `Module` property that you can set to `Current Product Module` (it appears automatically), so you don't need to use prefixes.

[image: Xcode Core Data editor]

Comment: This is what I typically overlook -- the most common "quick fix" to this error in my experience is doing exactly this.

Answer (score 31):

When using Swift the error could still appear also if the source file is included in the *Build Phases > Compile Sources* the error

> unable to load class named '...' for entity '...'. 
>   class not found, using default nsmanagedobject instead.

To solve this you could prefix the specific model class in the model inspector (here with *MyApp*). [See also the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html).

[image]

Our you can add `objc(Person)` before your swift class declaration

```
@objc(Person)
class Person: NSManagedObject {
   ...
}
```

Comment: @objc(<classname>) also did the trick for me. But, so did removing the "class" portion and just keeping "name" which may be a better solution for some people. Thank you High6

Comment: Xcode 12.4 will automatically remove the '.' when you press Enter.

Answer (score 17):

There is a similar answer to this question. In my case I was using Objective-C and doing this got rid of this error in the console.

I found the answer here: [Unable to find specific subclass of NSManagedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076276/unable-to-find-specific-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject)

*You can empty the "Module" field (it will show "None") and mark the managed object subclasses with @objc(classname)*

[image]
This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Xcode 7 beta the actual solution is **removing** the `@objc(Person)`. Must be a bug in the template that is used for generating entity classes in Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: This also worked for me. Swift is such a dynamically-changing language. Someday, it'll settle down...

Comment: I'm having the problem after a migration which adds an entity to the model. Core Data seems unable to see the newly created class related to the new entity. Removing objc() in the new class worked for me... however now in the project I have the new class with objc and all other old classes which don't have objc (the old classes still work ).

Answer (score 2):

Having this issue with SPM.

My model is being loaded from Bundle.module. But none of the classes can be found when trying to access them at runtime

Answer (score 0):

When none of the solutions worked for me, I deleted the existing 
NSManagedObject and created a new one. If you need any code from the previous object remember to take a backup, and later copy that into the new NSManagedObject class.
Hope this helps someone.