# Swift cast NSManagedObject to subclessed class fails

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an array of NSManagedObjects.
of which here is a truncated println:

```
[<NSManagedObject: 0x7f9cbc18cf30> (entity: PTKRMessage; id: 0xd00000000004001a <x-coredata://7EEF4956-FA8F-4DE9-B94C-CF612B40AA77/PTKRMessage/p1> ; data: {...}), <NSManagedObject: 0x7f9cbc18d790> (entity: PTKRMessage; id: 0xd00000000008001a <x-coredata://7EEF4956-FA8F-4DE9-B94C-CF612B40AA77/PTKRMessage/p2> ; data: {...})]
```

When I try to assign one element to a variable as the NSManagedObject Subclass (PTKRMessage)

```
let message = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as! PTKRMessage
```

I got the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSManagedObject_PTKRMessage_' (0x7f9cbc320d10) to 'tradersofdom.PTKRMessage' (0x102dda910).
```

PTKRMessage is defined in PTKRMessage.swift as:

```
class PTKRMessage: NSManagedObject {
     @NSManaged var content: String
     ...
}
```

it could be related to [cast NSManagedObject to class -> Swift dynamic cast failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565112/cast-nsmanagedobject-to-class-swift-dynamic-cast-failed) but the situation and error message is different.

Comment: Did you try the various solutions to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076276/unable-to-find-specific-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject?

Comment: Did you set the class in the CoreData model editor?

Comment: Yes I both tried adding @objc(PTKRMessage) and adding tradersofdom.PTKRMessage as class to the entity inspector. (Xcode 6.4 already prefixes it with PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME.PTKRMessage). Error message remains the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613971/coredata-warning-unable-to-load-class-named)

Comment: Try this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26614152/427083

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to

```
@objc(PTKRMessage)
class PTKRMessage: NSManagedObject {
     @NSManaged var content: String
     ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: What class name are you using in the XCode core data model.  Remove the module name prefix if there is one.