# Fetching the most recent item from CoreData in Swift

Tags: core-data, swift

I'm new to CoreData, have read a few tutorials but have come up empty-handed. Most tutorials have centered around fetching from CoreData to populate a tableview, which is not what I'm doing at the moment.

Here's how I'm setting the data in CoreData. All types are `Double` except for date which is an `NSDate`

```
let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)

let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Meditation", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
let meditation = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

meditation.setValue(settings.minutes, forKey: "length")
meditation.setValue(settings.warmup, forKey: "warmup")
meditation.setValue(settings.cooldown, forKey: "cooldown")
meditation.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "date")

// fetch stuff from CoreData
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Meditation")
var error:NSError? = nil
var results:NSArray = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!

for res in results {
    println(res)
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do to get the results, but I'm not able to access things like `.minutes`, `.date`, etc. I know I'm also not properly getting the last item either, I was just trying to print out attributes on the object first.

**I'd love help on how to fetch only the most recent object as well as show it's attributes**

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, create a "Meditation.swift" file in Xcode with "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject
Subclass ...". The generated file should look like

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Meditation: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var length: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var warmup: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var cooldown: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var date: NSDate

}
```

Now you can use the properties directly instead of Key-Value Coding
and create the object as

```
let meditation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Meditation", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as Meditation
meditation.length = ...
meditation.warmup = ...
meditation.cooldown = ...
meditation.date = NSDate()

var error : NSError?
if !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
    println("save failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

When fetching the object, cast the result of 
`executeFetchRequest()` to `[Meditation]`:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Meditation")

var error : NSError?
let result = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
if let objects = result as? [Meditation] {
    for meditation in objects {
        println(meditation.length)
        println(meditation.date)
        // ...
    }
} else {
    println("fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Finally, to fetch only the latest object, add a sort descriptor to
sort the results by date in descending order, and limit the number of results to one:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Meditation")
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
request.fetchLimit = 1
// ...
```

Then the `objects` array contains at most one object, which is the most recent one.

Comment: Martin, this is an awesome answer. Thank you. I was missing the subclass which is really helpful.

One thing: I'm getting an error on the line `managedObjectContext.save(&error)` related to the `&error` error pointer

Comment: @ZackShapiro: You'll need `var error : NSError?` as in the fetch request, I have added it to the code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. After running all of this, I get it to print out the `.length` and `.date` values, then it hits a breakpoint and tells me `CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Meditation' for entity 'Meditation'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.`

Comment: Stems from the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` line

Comment: @ZackShapiro: That's a well-known issue, see (for example) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076276/unabled-to-find-specific-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject. (Christer's answer is perhaps the easiest solution.)

Comment: Ah. Got it. I fixed it by putting @objc(Meditation) above the class declaration in Meditation.swift. Thanks again for your help. This is a phenomenal answer.