# Core Data: Fetch for the latest record from filtered elements

Tags: ios, core-data

What do I have: Core Data and its table 'Visitors' with some fields like 'personName', 'date', 'floor', 'section'.

What do I want: to construct the Fetch Request for getting the latest (by 'date') entry inside the set of Visitors filtered by concrete 'floor' and 'section'.

In others words, I need to get the name of the last visitor of X'th floor and its Y'th section. With plain SQL this could be done by something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Visitors where floor='2' and section='1' GROUP BY floor HAVING MAX(date)
```

or

```
SELECT personName, date, MAX(date) FROM Visitors WHERE floor='2' and section='1'
```

How I can do this using Fetch Request?..

Comment: This should get you started: [Fetching the most recent item from CoreData in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533764/fetching-the-most-recent-item-from-coredata-in-swift).

Comment: But I don't need just find the latest visitor. I need to find the latest visitor of concrete floor + section.

Comment: That's why I said "get you started" instead of closing as a duplicate :) – You have to add a *predicate* which restricts the result set to the floor/section.

Comment: Wow. I found myself just being stupid at this time. I had incorrect values in my local database, so the correct Fetch Request based on simple Predicate that I have tested before asking here, was really correct. But the incorrect stored values had been causing the incorrect result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with regular Fetch Request based on just predicate and descending order.