# Failed to create an object in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I have created a demo (cocoa) in storyboard with coredata selected. 
I have a `tableview` and `NSArrayController` in one of the viewcontroller on storyboard. 
 
 Two buttons `add` and `remove` are added which are connected to `NSArraycontroller`. But when I click on `add` it gives me an exception like `Failed to create an object`.

Please help. I am new to cocoa development

Comment: click of array controller - > Under bindings -> managedobjectcontext - >manageObjectContext.                                                                                   In the viewcontroller where NSArraycontroller is present i have added a method as     return ((AppDelegate*)([NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate)).managedObjectContext;
And i have created a button "Add" below the tableview and i have connected that to nsarraycontroller :add method

Comment: Did you set the entity of your arraycontroller?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the field from class to entity and given the particular entity name in the field of entity name

Comment: What is the exact text of the exception?

Comment: "Failed to create an object". When i created new project with coredata i had added only one entity . Now I added one more entity to the core data its giving exception "Failed to create Object"

Comment: [Failed to Create Object - Simple Core Data App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592954/failed-to-create-object-simple-core-data-app)?

Comment: Yes, Working on coredata. When created project  single entity was there and when i add new entity it shows "Failed to create an object"