# Swift 2, warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache

Tags: xcode, core-data, console, swift2, xcode7

I have found a few questions regarding this issue, yet none of them were helping with my problem. I am trying to save an object to core data using this code (which worked perfectly fine in Xcode 6 and Simulator...):

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Patient")
let fetchedResults : [NSManagedObject]!
do {
    fetchedResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
    patienten = fetchedResults
}    catch {
    print("error")
}
```

I added the do-try-catch once I started working on this project in the Xcode 7 beta and a physical device. 
Now, when I hit the Save button, this piece of code is called, the app freezes and I get the following:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anybody know where I went wrong?

Comment: I would suggest changing your print statement to actually printing out the error:  `print("Error: \(error)")` and then see what the actual error is.

Comment: The warning you got tends to happen whenever you use swift in the current version of Xcode. It may or may not be related to your problem.

Answer (score 23):

For anyone coming across this in the future, I just ran into this problem myself and it turned out that I was actually getting a stack overflow from a recursive function.

Apparently calling `setValue:forKey:` on an NSObject calls the respective `set[Key]` function, where `[Key]` is the (capitalized) name you gave to the `forKey` section.

So, if like me, you have code that looks like the following, it will cause an infinite loop and crash.

```
func setName(name: String) {
    self.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
}
```

Comment: Had a different scenario, but same problem, infinite recursion. The error is totally misleading. +1

Comment: :) had also same but i am adding dictionary object into the same dictionary like NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setValue:dict forKey:API_PARAM];

Answer (score 14):

## Choose `Product` > `Clean`

I had similar issue. I deleted the app from the device. Then "Product->Clean" in the XCode menu. When I ran the app again, the issue got resolved.

Comment: Thanks fixed it for me too, on XCode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)

Comment: Issue fixed this way on XCode v7.3.1

Comment: Fixed it for me too. Should be the accepted Answer. Another symptom of the problem: NSSet and NSArray did not expose their elements in the debugger’s Variables/Values pane. After a Product > Clean, (a) error message disappeared, and (b) collection elements appeared in pane.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 3:

Actually this problem happened often when you have any property in input declared as type `NSError` and the compiler expect an `Error` output, so change the input type to `Error` usually solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me in similar problem (xCode 7, Swift 2):

reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076276/unable-to-find-specific-subclass-of-nsmanagedobject/31288029#31288029)

Or more quickly without explaining the reason of solution: just comment `@objc(className)` in your `NSManagedObjectSubclass` , that was generated from your CoreData Entity (`@objc(Patient)` - in your case ).

This solution (if issue still appears) does not applicable to xCode 7.1/Swift 2.1, as the way of generating `NSManagedObjectSubclasses` was changed.

Don't forget about cleaning your project (`Product > Clean`) and deleting the app from your device/simulator to replace CoreData storage on it.

Comment: Is it something you were looking for?)

Answer (score -1):

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Patient")

do {
  let fetchedResults = try managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
  print("\(fetchedResults)")
} catch {
  print("error")
}
```

The above code worked for me.
Maybe the issue maybe with how your core data is managed.

1. Check if your `managedObjectContext` is actually getting created.
2. Check the modelling of your core data