# Quicksort Error when sorting large array

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I get an error message when I try to sort an array of one hundred thousand ints(I've tested the sort and it works for fifty thousand):

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

I also have the compare method iteratively and the same error appears

Why is this error message happening?

Is it possible to sort that list and if so how to fix it?

```
-(void) quickSort{
   return [self quickSort:0 pivot:[self.toSort count]-1 right: [self.toSort count]-1];
}

-(void) quickSort:(int) left pivot:(int) pivot right:(int) right {
    if(left < right){
        pivot = [self compareToPivot:[[self.toSort objectAtIndex:right] intValue] start:left finish:right position:left];
        [self quickSort:pivot+1 pivot:pivot right:right];
        [self quickSort:left pivot:pivot right:pivot-1];
    }

}

-(int) compareToPivot:(int) pivot start:(int)start finish:(int)finish position:(int)pos{
    if(pos == finish){
        [self switchNums:start second:finish];
        return start;
    }
     if([[self.toSort objectAtIndex:pos] intValue] <= pivot){
     [self switchNums:pos second:start];
     return [self compareToPivot:pivot start:start+1 finish:finish position:pos+1];
}
return [self compareToPivot:pivot start:start finish:finish position:pos+1];
}

-(void) switchNums:(int)first second:(int)second{
    id temp = [self.toSort objectAtIndex:second];
    [self.toSort replaceObjectAtIndex:second withObject:[self.toSort objectAtIndex:first]];
    [self.toSort replaceObjectAtIndex:first withObject:temp];
}
```

Iterative Compare and this runs fine:

```
-(int) compareToPivot:(int) pivot start:(int)start finish:(int)finish position:(int)pos{

while(pos != finish){
    if([[self.toSort objectAtIndex:pos] intValue] <= pivot){
        [self switchNums:pos second:start];
        start+=1;
    }
        pos++;
}
[self switchNums:start second:finish];
return start;
```

}

Comment: You're almost certainly seeing a stack overflow here — this is recursing too deep and causing unrelated memory corruption. Can you post your iterative version as well so we can see what it's doing? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431287/swift-2-warning-could-not-load-any-objective-c-class-information-from-the-dyld

Answer (score 1):

While Quicksort itself is considered a recursive algorithm, the partition step (your `comparetoPivot` method) is not meant for recursion.  And your implementation of this method is not only recursive, but it also is O(N) as far as stack space is concerned.  You only recurse with one less element than before with each recursion into compareToPivot.  Blowing up (running out stack) at around 100K elements sounds is to be expected as the default stack is around 500KB.

I used your question as an excuse to practice my Obj-C, which I'm a bit rusty on.  But here's the implementation of recursive Quicksort straight out of the classic [Algorithms (Cormen et. al.) book](http://a.co/7aPyXwO) and adapted for your `toSort` array.  I haven't tested it all out yet, but you can certainly give it a whirl.

```
-(int)partition: (NSMutableArray*)arr pivot:(int)pivot  right:(int)right
{
    int x = [[arr objectAtIndex: pivot] intValue];

    int i = pivot;
    int j = right;

    while (true)
    {

        while ([[arr objectAtIndex: j] intValue] > x)
        {
            j--;
        }

        while ([[arr objectAtIndex: i] intValue] < x)
        {
            i++;
        }

        if (i < j) {
            id objI = [arr objectAtIndex: i];
            id objJ = [arr objectAtIndex: j];
            [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:objJ];
            [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:objI];
            j--;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            return j;
        }
    }

}

-(void)quickSort
{
    int len = (int)[self.toSort count];
    [self quicksort:self.toSort left:0 right:(len-1)];
}

-(void)quicksort: (NSMutableArray*)arr left:(int)left  right:(int)right
{
    if (left< right)
    {
        int q = [self partition:arr pivot:left right:right];
        [self quicksort: arr left:left  right:q];
        [self quicksort: arr left:(q+1) right:right];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested the code and it wasn't working probably a few minor errors or something but I just added my iterative method for comparing the pivot(tested on smaller arrays). And  what you're saying(just so I'm clear) is that because my compare method is recursive that's why the error happens?

Comment: @smcavoy19 - I fixed my code above and tested it.  Should work now.  And yes, you're compare method is recursive and is guaranteed to require as many as N stack recursions.  You run out of stack space.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also realized my iterative method wasn't correct and that's why that one wasn't working. I also figured out that you can increase your stack size on a setting on your computer if you're interested take a look at that(I wouldn't use it for the recursion of course but maybe to reach even larger arrays).