# How can I access core data details from Today Extensions(iOS 8)?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, core-data, today-extension

I want to access some core data details from Today Extension.

1) Is it possible to access core data details from Today Extension(iOS8) ?

2) How do I access the core data details ?
Please give some ideas and suggestions.

Comment: what happened when you tried using google? why were the results unsatisfactory? have you tried anything yourself? what happened?

Comment: Yes. I tried like this but not getting the results. Can you give some more ideas..? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407428/how-to-access-coredata-model-in-today-extension-ios

Comment: Tell us what you found and why it was unsatisfactory for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links might helpful as they were to me

[Swift - Sharing Core Data Model in App Group (w/ extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443068/swift-sharing-core-data-model-in-app-group-w-extension)

[I can't use my core data model in two targets in a Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242173/i-cant-use-my-core-data-model-in-two-targets-in-a-swift-project?lq=1)

http://blog.sam-oakley.co.uk/post/92323630293/sharing-core-data-between-app-and-extension-in-ios